# Remove from Grid View ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net. I created an admin page that has radio buttons, search button, remove button and search text box for data using SQL procedure select. Once I insert a letter the text box,a grid view appears with selected data from the database into my web page! The admin can select a cell at once and can only delete one record from the  Remove button. My problem is this remove button can't work functionally!

Comment: Don't tag this question as ASP-CLASSIC its a ASP.NET question

Comment: You have to load and assign the `DataSource` again after you've deleted it and before you call `grid.DataBind();`. Otherwise the grid still shows the old content which is stored in `ViewState` by default.

Comment: Do you mean assign in the within the btnRemove?

Answer (score 0):

```
grid.DataBind();
```

Your code is fine. This grid.DataBind() will refresh data source and load updated data. Make sure you have deleted 
and committed your delete statement into DB.

If you bind the grid dataSource from code, set dataSource again after Deleting Record.

Comment: I used this method in Main Table class which                                   public bool Unsubscribe(string username)
    {
        this.Username = username;                              
        return Delete();
    }                                                                   I don't know why still not deleting !!? Do I need to set datasource in the grid view?